# Getting Error "Can't pickle" while saving keras model

Tags: python, keras, pickle, bert-language-model

I build a model with BERT pre-trained model, then I tried to save it using pickle I got this error

**Can't pickle <function LayerCall.**call** at 0x7f3f6a88a8c0>: it's not the same object as tensorflow.python.keras.saving.saved_model.save_impl.LayerCall.**call****

**UPDATE**:

I tried to save it with model.save() method but I got: **IndexError: list index out of range**

**Here is my Code to build the model**:

```
MAX_LENGTH = 35
INPUT_IDs = Input(shape=(MAX_LENGTH,), dtype=tf.int32, name="input_ids")
INPUT_MASK = Input(shape=(MAX_LENGTH,), dtype=tf.int32, name="attention_mask")

 embeddings = bert_model([INPUT_IDs, INPUT_MASK])[1] # 0 is hidden state, 1 is pooler_output

 out = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(embeddings)
 out = Dense(128, activation="relu")(out)
 out = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(out)
 out = Dense(32, activation="relu")(out)

 y = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(out)
 model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[INPUT_IDs, INPUT_MASK], outputs=y)
 model.layers[2].trainable = True


 optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=5e-06,
             epsilon=1e-08,
             decay=0.01,
             clipnorm=1.0)

 loss = BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
 metric = BinaryAccuracy('accuracy')

 model.compile(
     optimizer=optimizer,
     loss=loss,
     metrics=metric)

 train_history = model.fit(
     x={'input_ids':X_train["input_ids"], 'attention_mask':X_train["attention_mask"]},
     y=y_train,
     validation_split=0.2,
     epochs=10,
     batch_size=24)
```

Comment: We need to see your code.

Comment: @2e0byo ok, I updated the question with my code.

Comment: Where do you call model.save()?

Comment: after fitting the model "model.fit()" finished, I call model.save() @2e0byo